# Why this main method is not getting terminated?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithreading in java and I am trying to write a simple program to simulate inter-thread communication.

The problem is that my `main` method is not terminating until I swap the below two lines.

```
t1.start();// if I call t2.start() first and then t1.start() then it works perfectly
t2.start();
```

Can someone please explain **why do I need to call t2.start() before t1.start()?**

Here's my code

```
public class WaitNotifyExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("main method starts");
        A a = new A();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    a.printNumbers();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    a.afterPrintNumbers();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // This works fine but I don't understand why..
        t2.start();
        t1.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("main method ends");
    }

}

class A{
    public void printNumbers() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            this.notify();
        }
    }
    public void afterPrintNumbers() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(this){
            this.wait();
            System.out.println("all no. printed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I call t2.start() first and then t1.start() then it works perfectly

Not guaranteed.

---

Just consider, `t1` execute `this.notify();` first, then `t2` execute `this.wait();`.

In this situation, `t2` will never get signal.

Comment: Isn't it actually guaranteed here because if `t2` executes `this.wait()` first, then `t1` will never reach `this.notify()` because `t2` is holding the synchronized lock? Am I missing something?

Comment: To make this explicit: starting t1 first makes this scenario more likely, but starting t2 first still makes it possible. It's very important with multithreading code to prove that the behavior you want is not just possible, not just likely, but is the only possible behavior. Otherwise, it's likely to fail occasionally and in production, where it's extremely hard to diagnose and fix

Comment: @marstran Just because t2.start() gets called first, it doesn't mean _any_ of its run() method will run first. The JVM of perfectly within its rights to start the thread, immediately park it, and do other work (including starting t1).

Comment: @yshavit great explanation.

Comment: @yshavit Yes, but don't we really only have two cases here: Either `t1` enters the synchronized block first, or `t2` will. If `t1` enters the synchronized block first, then it will call `notify` when no thread is waiting (`t2` might be blocking against the synchronized lock, but it won't be affected by `notify`, right?). If `t2` is entering the synchronized block first, then it will call `wait` while still holding the synchronized lock, causing `t1` to never reach `notify`. It seems to me that both cases will reach a deadlock. Is there a case where both threads can terminate?

Comment: @marstran wait() causes the thread to give up its ownership of the lock and wait for a wake-up. That first part (releasing the lock) is crucial for preventing exactly the deadlock you mentioned in the second case. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--

Comment: @yshavit Ah, that's the detail I missed. Thanks.

Comment: @marstran Happy to help!

Comment: @marstran when you call wait，it will release the lock

Answer (score 1):

The order of the thread execution is not guaranteed and it depends on thread scheduler algorithm.

So In your case JVM is picking t1 and completes executing `this.notify()` before t2 executes `this.wait()` as mentioned earlier.